# Enabling notifications in Opera

Tags: notifications, opera

I have a [very simple test](http://botcompany.de/1011449/raw) for browser notifications. It works fine in Chrome, but in Opera 49 it says "permission: denied", even though in my Opera settings I have allowed all notifications.

This is my source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window.Notification) alert("Notifications not available");
    else {
      alert("Permission: " + Notification.permission);
      if (Notification.permission !== "denied")
          Notification.requestPermission(function(status) {
            var n = new Notification("Notify.", { 
                  body: "Hello Mama!"
            }); 
        });
    }
  </script>Notifying.
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I have this problem too. Found you a answer? Notification.requestPermission() results in "denied" for Opera. Chrome and Firefox working fine.

Comment: Same here more than 2 years later :(